# pd.read_html reads an empty table

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have two general questions:

1. I am scraping a table from a website using pd.read_html, and it worked before. It seems that the website was updated and the same pd.read_html now returns an empty table, even though there is a table on the webpage. It just returns the columns with empty entries. I tried beautifulsoup, request, and now will try selenium.
2. The table used to have around 500 entries, but you could select how many to show per page, max of 50, and the webpage divides the table into multiple pages. When I used pd.read_html before, it retrieved all the 500 entries at once rather than what's showing on the screen at that moment. I fail to understand where pd.read_html is retrieving the table content from since they are supposed to be in subsequent pages that I need to click "next" to appear. I actually want the 500 results at once. On another webpage of the same website, I am able to retrieve only what's on that page (i.e. the first 10) entries rather than the full 500 entries at once.

   Thank you

Comment: read_html searches for **table tag** in the page, manualy inspect the page to verify if tags exists.

Comment: Hmmm, tags don't show when I do soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml"), but I see them when I check the source in the browser!

Comment: Those tables might be getting rendered dynamicaly, you can verify it by doing ```wget <url>``` & see if resulting file has the required tags or not.